# Locking two different resources

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to lock two different resources using the Lockable Resources Plugin?

I would like to configure my job to lock one resource from the label "Apples" and one resource from the label "Pears".

I'm using the newest plugin version (1.11.2) and jenkins 2.251 and couldn't find how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that is possible if using the Freestyle job type.  If you're using Pipeline, however, you should be able to nest [`lock` steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/#code-lock-code-lock-shared-resource).  For example:

```
lock('apple') {
  lock('pear') {
    // Now we have exclusive access to both resources
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some other reason I cannot use pipelines in my setup unfortunately.

Comment: my problem is, that I want to run several small testjobs in parallel and want the parent job to hold a lock. Using pipelines I can't find how to use the "parallel" step and wrap it in a "lock" step. If you have any hints let me know.

Comment: If you're using Declarative Pipeline, you probably can't do that; otherwise I imagine it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a more coincise syntax to lock multiple named resource as the developers point in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/lockable-resources-plugin/issues/169#issuecomment-562926700):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
         // Pipeline scoped multiple resource lock
        lock(extra: [[resource: 'resa'], [resource: 'resb']])
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                 // Stage scoped multiple resource lock
                lock(extra: [[resource: 'resc'], [resource: 'resd']])
                {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```